# Can I Set Initial State with Props in React + Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, lodash

I'm having an issue where a state I have is showing as undefined and I suspect it might be because I'm passing the intial state as props.

Here's what the useState statement looks like:

```
const [filteredData, setData] = useState(props.cardsToShow);
```

I have cardsToShow as a state defined within MapStateToProps like this

```
cardsToShow: searchCards(state)
```

and it is populating based on the following search statement i have. note that baseball is the initial data load and search is a search query in store.

```
const searchCards = ({ baseball, search }) => {
  return search
    ? baseball.filter(a =>
        a.title[0].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
      )
    : baseball;
};
```

If i console log `props.cardsToShow` i get data which is an object of arrays.

If i console log `filteredData` i get an empty object.

Any ideas?

Comment: You said that if you `console.log(props.cardsToShow)` you get the proper data. Is it the first console.log after component mount? Or before that log you receive undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood it well, you are facing the problem covered below.

According to this article:

https://learnwithparam.com/blog/how-to-pass-props-to-state-properly-in-react-hooks/

useState doesn't initialize on props change, so you should set the state on useEffect instead

```
useEffect(() => {
    setData(props.cardsToShow);
}, [props]);
```

Comment: i just tried your suggestion Rander and it actually works perfectly now.  is there a reason you got downvoted, because (although i'm new) i think it's a good suggestion.  Thanks!

Comment: @JohnRogerson It got downvoted since it's just a workaround, not a deep fix

Comment: I will try to improve my answers next time. Thanks for both feedbacks

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways of doing it with Redux, you can set initial state for your reducer by using default parameters.

```
const defaultState = {
    state: 0
}

function counter(state = defaultState, action) {
...
```

Or if you use selectors

```
const getSomeValues = store => store.someValue || 1
```

if `someValue` is `undefined`, we will get 1 instead.

For a deeper explanation: https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/initializing-state

If you are using lodash, it has the `get` function, which allows you to specify a default value should a property return undefined. https://lodash.com/docs/#get